# Wordpress conditional display of page title inside the the_content using functions.php

Tags: function, wordpress-theming, wordpress

**Quick overview:**
I am trying to get the page title to display inside the_content(), however this needs to be conditional, and only display if the page has an attached image. This also needs to be done through the functions file.

**Where i've got up to:**
This is the code i have so far... but it's not working, and i think the problem is that it's outside the loop... how can i work the code to lookup the page id... or how can i get it to work?

```
<?php

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        add_filter('the_content', 'contentTitle');
            function contentTitle($content='')
            {
                $theTitle = '<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';
                return $theTitle . $content;
            }
        } else {
                // Do nothing
            } 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should globalise the post object so that the post ID is available.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'contentTitle');

function contentTitle($content='')
{
 global $post;
 if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ){ 
   $theTitle = '<h1>' . get_the_title( $post->ID ) . '</h1>';
   return $theTitle . $content;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The "if" should have been inside the function itself.

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content', 'contentTitle');

function contentTitle($content='') {

   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   $theTitle = '<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';
   return $theTitle . $content;

   } else {

   // Do nothing

   }
}
?>
```